# XSLT from XML to XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I haven this XML, I will transform to XML with XSLT,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Impleo_JobTransaction xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <OrderID>13040</OrderID>
   <OrderProductionInfo>
    <productName>Kriminalforsorgen visitkort DK</productName>
    <orderQuantity>200</orderQuantity>
    <orderPagecount>1</orderPagecount>
    <PageWidth>85.00</PageWidth>
    <PageHeight>55.00</PageHeight>
    <deliveryDays>0</deliveryDays>
    <productionInfo>offset</productionInfo>
    <productionFileNames>
      <string>O13040__32821_51_Kriminalforsorgen visitkort DK_e04710c326464273b99e60b0a25e7cd7.pdf</string>
    </productionFileNames>
    <ProductionSelections />
  </OrderProductionInfo>
 </Impleo_JobTransaction>
```

and will haven a new xml like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns0:ApoXML xmlns:ns0="http://www.agfa.com/apoxml" OrderNumber="ApoXML-BusinessCard" JobName="BusinessCard" Comments="ApoXML for single Business card. v3" Amount="5000" ProductType="Flatwork" AgentName="ApoXML SDK" AgentVersion="1.1" Unit="mm" DecimalSeparator=",">
    <CustomerContact>
        <Company Company="ApoXML Graphics NV" JDFProductID="PI_CompApoXML"/>
        <Person FirstName="Koen" LastName="Van de Poel" FixPhone="12345" Email="apoxmlNV@123.com" JDFProductID="PI_Pers_apoxmlNV"/>
    </CustomerContact>
    <Binding Method="Unbound"/>
    <Part PartType="Plain" PartName="BusinessCards" Press="Large Press" WorkStyle="Duplex" Comments="business cards">
        <!-- adapt the URL to the content location on your server or remove it -->
        <Pages URL="file://be.local/dfs/data/be/GS/RD/EQAP_Testfiles/JDFtank/Content/BusinessCardCMYK_DS.pdf" PageCount="2" PageWidth="85" PageHeight="55"/>
        <Color NrColors="4"/>
        <PaperStock StockName="Businesscards" Weight="200" Grade="1" Thickness="0,2" SheetWidth="707" SheetHeight="500"/>
    </Part>
</ns0:ApoXML>
```

But I haven newer do it before, when variable are in one line. and I must insert more

```
 <xsl:value-of select=""/>
```

in same <>

```
<ns0:ApoXML xmlns:ns0="http://www.agfa.com/apoxml" OrderNumber="<OrderID>" JobName="BusinessCard" Comments="ApoXML for single Business card. v3" Amount="<orderQuantity>" ProductType="Flatwork" AgentName="ApoXML SDK" AgentVersion="1.1" Unit="mm" DecimalSeparator=",">
```

How should I do that. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add attributes to your nodes use

```
<ns0:ApoXML>
    <xsl:attribute name='OrderNumber'><xsl:value-of select="OrderID"/></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name='JobName'><xsl:value-of select="BusinessCard"/></xsl:attribute>
</ns0:ApoXML>
```

Comment: Or just `OrderNumber="{OrderID}"` AFAIR.

Comment: Thanks FonnParr, its was just that I what. So its work now THANKS